# UDP on iperf Windows 7 shows only 2.5 Mbps

Tags: udp, windows-7-x64, throughput, iperf

I tried to run an iperf test between two windows 7 laptops with one hosting a ad-hoc network. Specifically I wanted to see whether I could see a visible difference in throughput between the built in PCI card and a USB wifi adapter.

Unfortunately under both conditions I managed to see a total speed of 2.5 Mbps only.

Is Windows throttling my UDP bandwidth in some way or is iperf 2 not compatible with Windows 7?

I tested on a windows 7 to windows 10 PC as well and saw the same issue.

A wireshark trace shows almost no retries and most of the packets appear to be using 58.5 and above n rates.

However it appeared that data was being sent in bursts

[This image shows the graph of packets sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4ohY.png)

I couldn't find any information on this. I will try using iperf 3 in the meantime and also test the performace via a standard AP and update this question.

[This is a screenshot of the cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7bqX.png)
Thanks in Advance!

Update: Iperf3 showed much higher speeds. 60 Mbps or so. I'll probably need to read up on the differences between the two softwares. I don't really understand why this difference exists.

Comment: Can you include the graph and screenshot in your post?

Comment: They are linked to the question. It should appear if you click on the "the image shows the graph" and "This is a screenshot". Also I have an update to this. Iperf 3 showed much higher speeds. Proper 60 Mbps.